# Meta partial view gets rendered in the body tag instead of in the head tag

Tags: presentation

I have added `@Html.Partial("/Views/Common/Meta.cshtml", metaModel)` in the `<head>` tag in the page layout but the links and other tags present in the `meta.cshtml` file are getting rendered in the `<body>` tag.

Meta.cshtml
[image]

Layout
[image]

Comment: Did you make sure that you are using the correct Layout File associated with your page?

Comment: yes, already checked that

Comment: Can you include cshtml of both layout and meta files in your question?

Comment: @MarekMusielak added the screenshots for both the files

Comment: Remove all the `<input>` tags from your meta partial. Potentially they cause that `<head>` tag is closed automatically as they are not valid inside `<head>`

Comment: For SEO purposes, replace screenshots with code snippets

Comment: @TestUser What happen when you just add only a static HTML in your partial view and check if it renders perfectly?

Answer (score 0):

All elements after the first `<input>` tag will be rendered in the `<body>` tag, just put all `<input>` tags at the end of the partial view file.